# How to create a UITextField like find Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I'd to create a `UITextField` like find iPhone.

I used the follow code for the `UITextField`:


    `UIBezierPath *maskPathBotton = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:txtSenha.bounds
                                                         byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerBottomLeft|UIRectCornerBottomRight
                                                               cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(8.0, 8.0)];`

```
txtSenha.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;

CAShapeLayer *maskLayerBotton = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayerBotton.frame = txtSenha.bounds;
maskLayerBotton.path = maskPathBotton.CGPath;
maskLayerBotton.fillColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
maskLayerBotton.strokeColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
maskLayerBotton.lineWidth=1.5;

[txtSenha.layer addSublayer:maskLayerBotton];
```

But the result wasn't so good.

In the corners the strokes are a little more different than the other lines. How can I create the same `UITextField`. Sorry for my English and for no image, I don't have enough reputation to upload an image.

EDIT:
UITextField from Find Iphone
[image]

And this, is that I could.

[image]

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to create a custom view that has the look of a UITextView, with the box around it?

Comment: It's like a two UITextField together.I update the post with the links to the images.

Comment: If i am not wrong it is a uitableview with uitextfield in side cell.

Comment: use image in clearbackground color situation take a background image and put transparent textfeild on it

Answer (score 0):

if you want rounded corner try this

```
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Be sure to include `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to access this.

or

remove this line from your code

```
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

instead of

```
[textField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[textField.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
[textField.layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
```

Comment: I Cant to that
"textField.layer.cornerRadius = 10;"
Because I want to make rounded corners only in the top left and right in the first textField, and rounded corners bottom left and right in the second textField.